# Elasticsearch + WhatElse?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, postgresql, elasticsearch, couchdb

I have been dabbling with CouchDB but now I need ElasticSearch, for both text searching and very dynamic querying. While I am aware of the River Plugin, there seem to be some ElasticSearch users who are claiming that ES is their only database storage - which may or may not be stretching the truth on the reliability front.

So, what would you bolt ElasticSearch onto, for that warm and cozy feeling that documents are being safely stored?  While CouchDB + ES is a possibility, what about MongoDB + ES or even PostregSQL + ES?

While this is not a how to programming question, I believe it to be an excellent topic that would prevent many unnecessary how to questions, if answered and understood correctly. ;)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for that warm and cozy feeling that documents are being safely stored?

You can store everything in ES if you want, some data sets don't care about durability but ES has replica sets and other durability measures so durability isn't a huge issue.

The main problem I can tell from having used ES is that it has no journal for one, which could pose a problem but it is a straight to disk tech.

So that "warm and cozy" feeling is perfectly applicable to ES.

That's pretty much the length of the topic...not too interesting I know.